# Strange DateTime.ToBinary() results?

Tags: c#

I have the following code:

```
var today = DateTime.Now;
var newToday = new DateTime(today.Year, today.Month, today.Day, 23, 59, 59);
Debug.WriteLine($"Today: {today} | Today binary: {today.ToBinary()}");
Debug.WriteLine($"NewToday: {newToday} | NewToday binary: {newToday.ToBinary()}");
DateTime startOfPeriod;
var startBinary = 0L;
var endBinary = 0L;
var endOfPeriod = new DateTime(today.Year, today.Month, today.Day, 23, 59, 59);
Debug.WriteLine($"EndOfPeriod: {endOfPeriod} | EndOfPeriod binary: {endOfPeriod.ToBinary()}");

startOfPeriod = endOfPeriod.Subtract(TimeSpan.FromDays(1));
startOfPeriod = startOfPeriod.Add(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
startBinary = startOfPeriod.ToBinary();
endBinary = endOfPeriod.ToBinary();
Debug.WriteLine($"StartOfPeriod: {startOfPeriod} | StartOfPeriod Binary: {startBinary}");
Debug.WriteLine($"EndOfPeriod: {endOfPeriod} | EndOfPeriod Binary: {endBinary}");
```

And the output is:

```
Today: 30.03.2017 17:39:32 | Today binary: -8587107185125548526
NewToday: 30.03.2017 23:59:59 | NewToday binary: 636265151990000000
EndOfPeriod: 30.03.2017 23:59:59 | EndOfPeriod binary: 636265151990000000
StartOfPeriod: 30.03.2017 00:00:00 | StartOfPeriod Binary: 636264288000000000
EndOfPeriod: 30.03.2017 23:59:59 | EndOfPeriod Binary: 636265151990000000
```

**Why is the binary value (long) of `today` so much different from `newToday` ???**

I serialize dates to a Redis database where they are all negative (stored as strings). But when I do calculations as shown above I get those strange positive values! If you then search the DB of course there will be never any matching record!

Can anybody explain what is going on here??

Comment: DateTime.Now will have a Kind where your new DateTime does not. Specify a kind and observe the results `var newToday = new DateTime(today.Year, today.Month, today.Day, 23, 59, 59, DateTimeKind.Local);`

Comment: Consider using DateTimeOffset.Now

Comment: Ahh, everything clear. The correct constructor to use would be `var newToday = new DateTime(today.Year, today.Month, today.Day, 23, 59, 59, today.Kind);` Thanks!